# Forming image payload from exported SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, payload, object-detection-api

I've trained a model with the TF object detection API. This automatically exported a `variables` folder and `saved_model.pb`.  I ran `saved_model_cli show --dir <saved_model_path> --all` and got the output:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['serialized_example'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: ()
        name: tf_example:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40, 4)
        name: detection_boxes:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40)
        name: detection_classes:0
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40)
        name: detection_scores:0
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1)
        name: num_detections:0
    outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 204800, 4)
        name: raw_detection_boxes:0
    outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 204800, 2)
        name: raw_detection_scores:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

signature_def['tensorflow/serving/predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['serialized_example'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: ()
        name: tf_example:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40, 4)
        name: detection_boxes:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40)
        name: detection_classes:0
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 40)
        name: detection_scores:0
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1)
        name: num_detections:0
    outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 204800, 4)
        name: raw_detection_boxes:0
    outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 204800, 2)
        name: raw_detection_scores:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I then created a predict function with:

`predict_fn = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(<saved_model_path>)`

Now I'm stuck on constructing an image(s) payload to send to this. In particular I'm confused about the input name of `serialized_example`, input dtype of `DT_STRING`, and input shape of `()`. Would anyone please be willing to demonstrate how to take either a numpy array or jpeg image file and form a proper payload for this model?

Comment: It looks like the input type by default is `tf_example` instead of `image_tensor` or `encoded_image_string_tensor` so the default exporting may not be very useful.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?